# React useEffect equivalent in class component

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a React functional component that does the following:

- Sends a POST to load raw data from my API
- (Among other stuff) sends **mapped** data to a custom table component
- Allows the user to re-send the POST with a different fiter

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import mytable from "./mytable";

const baseRawData = [
  { name: "name", value: "John Doe" },
  { name: "sex", value: "M" }
];

export default function FuncComp() {
  let [rawData, setRawData] = useState(baseRawData);
  let [mappedData, setMappedData] = useState([]);
  let [apiFilter, setApiFilter] = useState("all");

  useEffect(() => {
    setMappedData(
      rawData.map(e => ({
        ...e
        // Some logic
      }))
    );
  }, [rawData]);

  useEffect(() => {
    axios.post(`/my/api/${filter}`).then(({ data }) => {
      setRawData(data);
    });
  }, [apiFilter]);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>The filter is '{apiFilter}'</h1>
      <mytable data={mappedData} />
      <input
        value={apiFilter}
        onBlur={e => setApiFilter(e.target.value)}
        type="text"
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

How would I, in a class component, achieve the same logic as **useEffect** to map the newly received raw data every time the user changes the filter and new raw data is received?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Use [life-cycle](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html)

Comment: @goto1 Using componentDidUpdate to check for when the array changes, but I couldn't figure out an efficient way to do it because it's an array of objects...

Comment: @Jason Use `React.PureComponent` + `immutable` for nesty compare check, or just `JSON.stringfy`

Comment: Show what you've done.

Comment: To be honest, the easiest way to check for a change in a nested object is use Lodashe's  isEqual() function. Nice and clean. I don't know how efficient that is though.

Comment: `componentDidMount()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before converting it back to a class component, I would simplify the functional one like this

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import mytable from "./mytable";

const baseRawData = [
  { name: "name", value: "John Doe" },
  { name: "sex", value: "M" }
];

const mapData = rawData => rawData.map(e => ({
  ...e
  // Some logic
}));

export default function FuncComp() {
  let [mappedData, setMappedData] = useState(mapData(baseRawData));
  let [apiFilter, setApiFilter] = useState("all");

  useEffect(() => {
    axios.post(`/my/api/${apiFilter}`).then(({ data }) => {
      setMappedData(mapData(data));
    });
  }, [apiFilter]);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>The filter is '{apiFilter}'</h1>
      <mytable data={mappedData} />
      <input
        value={apiFilter}
        onBlur={e => setApiFilter(e.target.value)}
        type="text"
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

and then you can convert useState in simple state vars.
I didn't run the code but it should be something like this.

```
import React from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import mytable from "./mytable";

const baseRawData = [
  { name: "name", value: "John Doe" },
  { name: "sex", value: "M" }
];

const mapData = rawData => rawData.map(e => ({
  ...e
  // Some logic
}));

class component extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    this.state = {
      mappedData: mapData(baseRawData),
      apiFilter: 'all'
    }
  }

  filterChanged(newApiFilter) {
    this.setState({apiFilter: newApiFilter});
    axios.post(`/my/api/${newApiFilter}`).then(({ data }) => {
      this.setState({
        mappedData: mapData(data)
      })
    });
  }

  render () {
    const {apiFilter, mappedData} = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>The filter is '{apiFilter}'</h1>
        <mytable data={mappedData} />
        <input
          value={apiFilter}
          onBlur={e => this.filterChanged(e.target.value)}
          type="text"
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: While simplification is a good idea, this manages to dodge the question actually being asked - how do you employ an equivalent of `useEffect` for when a dependency state has changed?  This basically says "don't try", which may not be viable for many situations.

Comment: Formik FieldArray removing item gives old array from prop, I have tried the below solution from https://github.com/formium/formik/issues/2934 from this post. It works absolutely fine.                                                


useEffect(() => {
  console.log(props.values.invoice_items);
}, [props.values.invoice_items]);                
Can we use class based hooks instead of functional useEffect ?

Answer (score 2):

This solution is based on the following assumptions;

1. You have a baseData you want to render when the component first render.
2. Once the component is mounted, you request new data from the api.
3. If the filter is empty, you make a request without the filter.
4. Once the filter value is set, you make another request with the filter.

**Code**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import mytable from "./mytable";

const baseRawData = [
  { name: "name", value: "John Doe" },
  { name: "sex", value: "M" }
];

export default class ClassComp extends Component{
  state = {
    rawData: baseRawData,
    mappedData: [],
    apiFilter: ""
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    axios.post(`/my/api`)
    .then(({ data }) => {
      this.setState({ mappedData : data });
    });
  }

  filterPost = (e) => {
    this.setState({ apiFilter: e.target.value},() => {
      axios.post(`/my/api/${this.state.apiFilter}`)
        .then(({ data }) => {
          this.setState({ mappedData : data });
        });
    });
  }

  render() {
    const {apiFilter, mappedData, baseRawData } = this.state;

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>The filter is '{apiFilter}'</h1>
      <mytable data={ mappedData ? mappedData : baseRawData } />
      <input
        value={apiFilter}
        onBlur={e => this.filterPost(e.target.value)}
        type="text"
      />
    </div>
  );
 }
}
```